# jquery SlideToggle in sections as section, ques and ans

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I was making a section with questions and answers, and want them to be hidden, till a user clicks on the relevant part of the section.
This is very similar to the question asked here :

[jquery Simple SlideToggle in sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622530/jquery-simple-slidetoggle-in-sections)

However, i have multiple questions in a section, flow being like :

All questions and answers are hidden. When someone clicks on a section, all the relevant questions in that section open up and when one clicks on the question, it's answer gets displayed.

When I click on another question, the previous open answer hides. and the relavent answer opens.
When an answer opens and someone clicks on another section, that section opens up hiding up all the other sections.

How does one do this??

Here is a sample jsfiddle, if someone can help.
http://jsfiddle.net/NpGMh/1/

Thanks.

Comment: The fiddle looks like you have something going. What is the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @David This only displays the immediate element, since next() is used. I want all the questions in the section to be displayed.

Comment: Aaditi is what i posted not what you want ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: Yes, solves most of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NpGMh/3/). I think that's what you intended. I used the `nextUntil` selector to get all siblings within that section up until the next section.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for.Thanks, just one thing, that within a section on the open answer, when I click on another question in the same section, it should close the open question. Will try to figure out a way. Thanks :D

Comment: Oh that might be just a `$('.answer:visible').slideToggle(500); ` off the top of my head, when a question is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the [jquery ui accordian](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Accordion#overview)?

Comment: cannot use the library, or a plugin,as it would turn out to be heavy for such a small feature.